# Prove $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac x {\sin x} \, \mathrm d x = 2\sum_{n\mathop = 0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$

Tags: definite-integrals

I would like to prove that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac x {\sin x} \, \mathrm d x = 2\sum_{n\mathop = 0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$$

Any hints?

Comment: In general when asked to compute some integral and show it is the same as a series, it is always good to check the Taylor expansions of the integrand. The technique in the answer by Robert below is widely applicable.

Comment: @AlfredYerger ...which I did, and if you look up the Taylor expansion of $x/\sin x$ you will see why that did not help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac x {\sin x} d x=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{2t}{2\sin t \cos t} d (2t)=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{t}{\tan t \cos^2 t}d t=2\int_0^{1}\frac{\arctan s}{s}d s\\
=2\int_0^{1}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n s^{2n}}{2n+1} ds
=2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\int_0^{1}\frac{ s^{2n}}{2n+1} ds
=2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Since $\ds{\totald{\ln\pars{\tan\pars{x/2}}}{x} = {1 \over \sin\pars{x}}}$:

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{x \over \sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x} & =
-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\tan\pars{x \over 2}}\,\dd x
\end{align}
With the *Weierstrass Tangent Half-Angle Substitution*:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{x \over \sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x} & =
-2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x =
-2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,x^{2n}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{-\,{1 \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}}} =
\color{#f00}{2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

Both expressions equal $2G$, where $G$ is the [Catalan constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)

Comment: That is a completely vacuous statement; certainly not a proof.

Comment: Not a proof, sure, an information. I thought the link could be useful.

Comment: @PaulEnta in these kind of situations, sharing the information using the comments part is a better idea.

Comment: I understand, but it necessitates more reputation. I'll wait :)